# Should a Windows Phone Application be uploaded to the marketplace as a release or debug build?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Windows Phone Application should be uploaded to marketplace in release 0r debug build?

I.E. in bin/debug

bin/Release

xap file should be from which directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Release` build.

It is a requirement of the marketplace certification requirements that your submitted application does not include debug symbols. See section 4.2.3 of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184844(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Select `Release` option in `Visual Studio` and get output file from `bin/Release`

Answer (score 0):

I actually sent my app in, which was built in debug mode... and it got through the certification.. but really it should be built in release mode... it was just a small free test app really. For my big app/game I will build it in "Release" mode